# GMS2 trigger for event not working properly

Tags: gml, game-maker-studio-2

(First of all i'm new to all of this so sorry in advance if this was a waste of time)

So I'm creating a game and decided to follow Friendly Cosmonaut's guide on triggers and cutscenes.
(link) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDLxCXexcxk

I followed everything there and created a few custom scripts and everything works like a charm on the first room, but when I try adding a trigger on the second room it just doesn't work at all.

For example, I create a trigger so when it collides with the player object, it makes the screen shake (as a test) and it creates an object in the room. But when the code is the following:

```
t_scene_info = [

    [screen_shake, 6, 1000],

]
```

(I'll provide code for all functions further in the post)
Nothing happens on collision, but when I change it to:

```
t_scene_info = [

    [screen_shake(6, 1000)],

]
```

The code runs before even the player has collided, as soon as the trigger object gets created.

(Again, I tried this in the first room with the first 2 triggers, and it works fine.)

Here's the code for:

oCutscene (Create event):

```
scene_info = -1;
scene = 0;

timer = 0;

scene_info = [
    [create_box_at_mouse],
    [cutscene_wait, 2],
    [create_box_at_mouse],
    [cutscene_wait, 4],
    [create_box_at_mouse]
];

event_perform(ev_other, ev_user0);

x_dest = -1;
y_dest = -1;
```

oCutscene (Step event):

```
script_execute_alt(current_scene[0], current_scene_array);
```

oCutscene (User event 0):

```
current_scene = scene_info[scene]

var len = array_length_1d(current_scene) -1;

current_scene_array = -1;
current_scene_array = array_create(len, 0);
array_copy(current_scene_array, 0, current_scene, 1, len);
```

oTriggerP (Step event) (The trigger that's supposed to execute the code when colliding with the player or playerd (just a dummy)):

```
if(!instance_exists(oCutscene)){    
  if(place_meeting(x, y, oPlayerD) || place_meeting(x, y, oPlayer)){
      create_cutscene(t_scene_info);
      instance_destroy();
  }
}
```

oTriggerP (Create event):

```
t_scene_info = -1;
```

create_cutscene (Script):

```
if(!instance_exists(oCutscene)){    
  if(place_meeting(x, y, oPlayerD) || place_meeting(x, y, oPlayer)){
        create_cutscene(t_scene_info);
        instance_destroy();
  }
}
```

cutscene_end_action (Script):

```
with(oCutscene){
  scene++;
  if(scene > array_length_1d(scene_info)-1){
        instance_destroy();
        exit;
  }
  event_perform(ev_other, ev_user0);
}
```

cutscene_wait (Script):

```
with(oCutscene){
  scene++;
  if(scene > array_length_1d(scene_info)-1){
        instance_destroy();
        exit;
  }
  event_perform(ev_other, ev_user0);
}
```

script_execute_alt (Script):

```
        ///@description script_execute_alt
    ///@arg ind
    ///@arg [arg1,arg2,...]

    var num1 = argument0;
    var a = argument1;
    var len = array_length_1d(argument1);

    switch(len){
        case 0 : script_execute(0) break;
        case 1 : script_execute(num1, a[0]); break;
        case 2:  script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1]); break;
        case 3:  script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2]); break;
        case 4:  script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]); break;
        case 5:  script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]); break;
        case 6:  script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]); break;
        case 7:  script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6]); break;
        case 8:  script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7]); break;
        case 9:  script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8]); break;
        case 10: script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9]); 
break;
        case 11: script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], 
a[10]); break;
        case 12: script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], 
a[10], a[11]); break;
        case 13: script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], 
a[10], a[11], a[12]); break;
        case 14: script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], 
a[10], a[11], a[12], a[13]); break;
        case 15: script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], 
a[10], a[11], a[12], a[13], a[14]); break;
        case 16: script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], 
a[10], a[11], a[12], a[13], a[14], a[15]); break;
        case 17: script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], 
a[10], a[11], a[12], a[13], a[14], a[15], a[16]); break;
        case 18: script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], 
a[10], a[11], a[12], a[13], a[14], a[15], a[16], a[17]); break;
        case 19: script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], 
a[10], a[11], a[12], a[13], a[14], a[15], a[16], a[17], a[18]); break;
        case 20: script_execute(num1, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], 
a[10], a[11], a[12], a[13], a[14], a[15], a[16], a[17], a[18], a[19]); break;
    }
```

screen_shake (Script):

```
///@arg Magnitude
///@arg Time
with(oCamera){

  if(argument0 > shake_remain){
    
      shake_magnitude = argument0;
      shake_remain = argument0;
      shake_length = argument1;
    
  }
      cutscene_end_action();

}
```

Here's the creation code for the 2 triggers in the first room:

First trigger (oTriggerP):

```
t_scene_info = [

[cutscene_move_character, oPlayerD, 800, 279, false, 1],
[cutscene_wait, 1],
[instance_create_layer, 0, 0, 0, oIntro],
[cutscene_move_character, oPlayerD, 1170, 279, false, 1],

];
```

Second trigger (Another oTriggerP):

```
t_scene_info = [

[cutscene_move_character, oPlayerD, 800, 279, false, 1],
[cutscene_wait, 1],
[instance_create_layer, 0, 0, 0, oIntro],
[cutscene_move_character, oPlayerD, 1170, 279, false, 1],
[room_goto(Prehistoric)]

];
```

I really don't think the cutscene_wait and cutscene_move_character scripts have anything to do with this but I'll throw 'em in just in case

cutscene_wait (Script):

```
/// @description
/// @arg second
with(oCutscene){
    timer++;

    if(timer >= argument[0] * room_speed){

        timer = 0;
        cutscene_end_action();

    }
}
```

cutscene_move_character (Script)

```
        with(oCutscene){
    var obj = argument0, relative = argument3, spd = argument4;

    if(x_dest == -1){
        if(!relative){
            x_dest = argument1;
            y_dest = argument2;
        } else{
            x_dest = obj.x + argument1;
            y_dest = obj.y + argument2;
        }
    }

    var xx = x_dest;
    var yy = y_dest;

    with(obj){
        sprite_index = sPlayerR;

            if(point_distance(x, y, xx, yy) >= spd){
            var dir = point_direction(x, y, xx, yy);
            var ldirx = lengthdir_x(spd, dir);
            var ldiry = lengthdir_y(spd, dir);

            if(dir != 0) { image_xscale = sign(ldirx); }

            x += ldirx;
            y += ldiry;
        }else {
            x = xx;
            y = yy;
    
            with(other){
                x_dest = -1;
                y_dest = -1;
                cutscene_end_action();
            }
        }

    }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your time and patience, and I apologize if I didn't include something or messed up on anything.

Comment: The `[screen_shake(6, 1000)]` part looks correct to me, you're calling a script that way. in `[screen_shake, 6, 1000]` makes it look like you've just defined an array, where `screen_shake` becomes a new variable. But the part that's not clear to me is where you define the `[screen_shake(6, 1000)]` part, is that in an On Collision Event? Or in a Create Event? Since November 2020, GameMaker Studio changed the scripts that they need to be within functions instead, so it's possible that's causing a problem as well if they're lacking.

Comment: It is in an On Collision event between oPlayer and oTriggerP. I've also tested [screen_shake, 6, 1000] and it works fine with the first room's triggers, and I tested if the collision system between oTriggerP and oPlayer works by destroying the instance of the trigger on collision, and it works, but the screen shake happens as soon as the player enters the room.